# Printing n newlines with printf

Tags: bash, printf

I have a numeric value stored in a bash variable `n` and want to use the number to introduce `n` newlines when using `printf` after the arguments.  How can I do this?

```
n=0
printf '%s\n' "$@"
printf '%s\n\n' ""

n=1
printf '%s\n' "$@"
printf '%s\n' ""

n=3
printf '%s\n' "$@"
printf '%s\n\n\n' ""
```

Comment: Hm.. while not great duplicate, most of the ideas `yes | head -n$n` `printf "%.0s\n" $(seq $n)` `perl -E 'say "\n" x '$n` from there will just work.

Comment: `printf '%*s' $n '' | tr ' ' '\n'`

Comment: Thought about using a loop but something is wrong in it `for (( n=1; n=nt; n++ )); do printf '%s\n' "" ; done`

Comment: `for ((i=0; i<n; ++i)); do echo; done`